# Subsetting/filtering for particular rows in R - with standard functions or dbplyr?

Tags: dataframe, dplyr, rstudio, row, subset

I am trying to subset data from the BLS to differentiate rows with NAICs codes into different categories. They are currently all in one column, with # lengths ranging from 2-6. Ideally, I would like to have my data frame include 4 new binary columns (0, 1) so that I could keep the data frame with all original values, and call on the new NAIC code columns separately.

Data:

```
naic_codes year             area_title          own_title                                             industry_title annual_avg_emplvl
1           10 2017 Kansas City, MO-KS MSA      Total Covered                                   101 Total, all industries           1031619
2           10 2017 Kansas City, MO-KS MSA Federal Government                                   10111 Total, all industries             26982
```

I have tried several methods to subset so that I could filter codes such just to their respective length entries. Variations I've attempted include filter, select, subset, changing values into factors/characters/numeric/integer.

`df3 %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("naic_codes")), any_vars(.<= 99))`

`new <- df2[nchar(df2$naics_code) ==2]`

I either get error messages or unused R arguments, new vectors with NULL values, or a new vector with the same values without any filtering.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Can you add an example of the desired output?

Comment: If I have a table such as the one below, I'd like the "naic_codes" column to be separated into different data frames depending on length. So the table below would could differentiate by row according to numeric length of NAIC codes:

`id  naic_codes yr    area  biz type`
`18          11 2017 KC,MO   Private`                       
19         111 2017 KC,MO   Private                                   
20        1111 2017 KC,MO   Private                       
21       11111 2017 KC,MO   Private                                
22      111110 2017 KC,MO   Private`

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do this would be to convert the column into factors and use 1 hot encoding